# Tkinter - The Reuleaux Triangle

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I need help creating a Reuleaux Triangle using Tkinter, *create_arc* method. I have tried creating one arc, but can't seem to figure how to control the coordinates properly, because you would neet to stretch the arc as an eclipse, which looks like circles but aren't actually.

A Reuleaux Triangle looks something like this:

[image]

I have tried one side, but can't seem to control the coordinates on how it should appear.

```
screen.create_arc(100, 100, 600, 600, fill="red")
```

This is my first time using this platform, sorry for any confusions and I appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume `(x, y)` is the coordinates of the bottom-left vertice of the triangle and `r` is the length of the triangle side, then the following function will draw the Reuleaux triangle:

```py
def create_reuleaux_triangle(canv, x, y, r, color='black'):
    # calculate the coordinates of the top vertice
    x1 = x + r / 2
    y1 = y - r * sin(radians(60))
    # draw the Reuleaux triangle
    canv.create_arc(x-r, y-r, x+r, y+r, extent=60, style='chord', outline=color)
    canv.create_arc(x, y-r, x+r+r, y+r, start=120, extent=60, style='chord', outline=color)
    canv.create_arc(x1-r, y1-r, x1+r, y1+r, start=240, extent=60, style='chord', outline=color)
```

Below is an example:

```
import tkinter as tk
from math import sin, radians

def create_reuleaux_triangle(canv, x, y, r, color='black'):
    # calculate the coordinates of the top vertice
    x1 = x + r / 2
    y1 = y - r * sin(radians(60))
    # draw the Reuleaux triangle
    canv.create_arc(x-r, y-r, x+r, y+r, extent=60, style='chord', outline=color)
    canv.create_arc(x, y-r, x+r+r, y+r, start=120, extent=60, style='chord', outline=color)
    canv.create_arc(x1-r, y1-r, x1+r, y1+r, start=240, extent=60, style='chord', outline=color)

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=300, height=300)
canvas.pack(fill='both', expand=1)

create_reuleaux_triangle(canvas, 50, 200, 200, 'red')

root.mainloop()
```

And the result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
screen.create_arc(100, 100, 600, 600, fill="red",style=tk.ARC)
```

See https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/create_arc.html for documentation